# How do I copy in vi editor?

Tags: clipboard, vi

I am using vi editor and I want to do copy operation but unable to do it. When I select the word and right click on it, there is no "copy"option but only "paste" option is there. What is wrong going on here? Is there is any package needs to be installed for vi/vim editor ?

**Note** : 
It could be better to obtain  "copy" option on selection for permanent fix but I got solution below i.e.to use yank command . Its is working fine within the file . But if there are 2 files open on separate tabs, I am still unable to copy data from one file to another. 
[image]

Comment: How about usual terminal text? Could you see a Copy option active not in vi? Then you could try a different terminal: `sudo apt install konsole`

Comment: Just press the middle key of your mouse to paste what you have highlighted

Comment: But if there are 2 files open on separate tabs, i am unable to copy data from one file to another. Is there way for this also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing up copy/paste in terminal and in vi/vim.

When you mark a word in the terminal, it is automatically copied, never mind if you are in vi or an other app, or just have some output from a command or even text you have written yourself.

In `vi` you copy with the `y` (yank) operator:

- `yy` copy whole line
- `yw` copy word (from cursor position til next whitespace.
- `y<space>` copy character

And paste with the `p` and `P` operators. Read the vi manual page for full documentation.

Also you could maybe use a graphical editor like `gedit`.

Comment: Yes you are right. yank operator (yy and yw) are working properly as you said . Also, can I do copy operation for the part of the sentence only( e.g. in the given image , the sentence part  " everyone i want to " ) ?

Comment: In the "visual mode" i could able to copy part of the sentence. 1st select visual mode using "v" then select the part of sentence, then do "yy" ,and finally do "p" operation

Comment: @AMITk `4yw` or `y4w` will copy 4 words, and `3yy` will copy 3 lines .. I don't know if it issomething like that you are asking for?

Comment: I got the idea from your answer. 4yw or y4w will copy 4 words, and 3yy will copy 3 lines .

Comment: yank command is working fine within the file . But if there are 2 files open on separate tabs, i am unable to copy data from one file to another. Is there way for this also?

Answer (score 1):

In some terminals you can use for copy:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

and for paste:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd>

Comment: this is not working in my case. Although i select the word and do operations as you said , pasting is not done